# When calling Python functions that make files and check if files exist, how can I run these functions such that they run in their own directory?

Tags: python

I'm working on a big project, and many of the functions that I call check for metadata located within the same directory that the functions and files are located in. However, if I call these functions from a parent script, the file checking and writing will be done in the parent directory, which is not what I want.

One alternative would be obviously to change all of the code to get the correct directories, but this is not practical because of the amount of files. So is there something I can do from the parent script to solve this?

Comment: @JoranBeasley so every time I call one of these functions will I need to os.chdir into the file directory?

Comment: well it looks in your current local directory ... so if thats all you have specified you must either specify more(ie full path) or change the environment to have its current local directory the one where the file exists ... those are really the only two answers ... and I'll tell you its much better to use an absolute full path